# translation is not executed for one transblock

Tags: python, django

I have this translation block

```
{% blocktrans with  car_type=car.get_car_type_display %}
 A 
 {{ car_type }}
 with chauffeur
 {% endblocktrans %}
```

and the translation in django.po

```
msgid ""
"\n"
"                                            A \n"
"                                            %(car_type)s\n"
"                                            with chauffeur\n"
"                                        "
msgstr ""
"\n"
"                                            Une \n"
"                                            %(car_type)s\n"
"                                            avec chauffeur\n"
"                                        "
```

But the translation doesn't seem to have an effect.

PS: There is no fuzzy tag.

Can you help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at all the pading I'm going to bet that its a whitespace issue, and your best bet is removing the whitespace to make translation easier - especially since the whitepsace will be stripped by the browser when it is seen by the user.

For pre-Django 1.6, you'll need to eliminate the whitespace yourself.

```
{% blocktrans with  car_type=car.get_car_type_display %}A {{ car_type }} with chauffeur{% endblocktrans %}
```

Fortunately, [Django 1.7 introduced the `trimmed` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag), so for Django1.7 and above, you can just add it, like so:

```
{% blocktrans trimmed with  car_type=car.get_car_type_display %}
 A 
 {{ car_type }}
 with chauffeur
 {% endblocktrans %}
```